# Assigning property to PFUser subclass

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I have a `PFUser` subclass which seems to be working properly. Therefore, when I try o assign that subclassed `PFUser` to a `property`, it doesn't work.

This is how I create the `PFUser` subclass:

user.h

```
@interface User : PFUser<PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@end
```

user.m

```
@implementation User

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"_User";
}
@end
```

Now, in a `PFObject` subclass I declare an object of the above class:
`@property (retain) User *usuario;`.

On a third class, I import both classes and try to assign the `PFUser`:

```
Subclass *diary = [[Subclass alloc] init];
diary.usuario = [User currentUser];
```

It does't work, it recognizes my `property`as being a `int`, not the `User` class. So I get the message that I can't assign pointer to int.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Sometimes I get the message "unknown type name user" when declaring the `User` object as a `property`in my subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You do not/should not need to implement `parseClassName` as it should always be the value returned by PFUser. Moreover, you have to register your subclass by calling:

```
[User registerSubclass];
```

for it to work.

See [this answer](https://www.parse.com/questions/subclass-pfuser) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I just removed. And I already had [User registerSubclass]. I still have the same problem.